# How much to increase page file value for SQL Server 2008 R2 Full Text Search Engine

Tags: sql-server, pagefile, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 Full-text search engine (FTS) is taking up too much resource (I/O & Memory) in my production server. (migrated from SQL server 2005).

I have been reading up on SQL Server FTS engine *[Internals and Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(SQL.100).aspx)* and there was a suggestion on how to improve FTS performance under *[Performance Improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(SQL.100).aspx#_Toc202506243)* section

> Increase the page file size if applicable.

But it doesn't mention **how much** page file size should be increased by.
Should it be adjusted thru trial & error?  or is there a rule of thumb I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/full_text_search_p1.aspx):

> The virtual memory (PAGEFILE.SYS file)
>   setting for your operating system
>   should be set to an amount equal to **3**
>   **times the amount of physical RAM** in
>   the server.

For example, if physical RAM is 8GB, then ideally you should allocate 24GB to VM.

You may be able to get away with less (1x-2x) but you'll need to perform some load testing to verify that.